# Receiving parse error for landing page HTML Body

Tags: marketing-cloud, html, landing-page

When trying to preview one of our landing pages, we are running into the error below. I can add HTML content if necessary.

> An unexpected error has occurred! Error Message:  An unrecognized
>   expression appears in a script block. Script Expression: EmailAddress
>   MemberID: 7001394 JobID: 0   Description: An unexpected error occurred
>   during the execution of the page.
>
> line 0, column 0 Exception Info: An error occurred when attempting
>   to parse HtmlEmailBody content for HTML content. MemberID: 7001394
>   JobID: 0 ListID: 0

```
Content Begins With: <!-- ET Logic -->
%%[ 
/* ExactTarget AMPscript */
@ActionDate, @ActionDateTime

SET @ActionDat
```

> ExactTarget.OMM.InvalidScriptException:  The SET variable value
>   expresion is invalid.  See inner exception for detail.   Script: set
>   @EmailAddress = EmailAddress   Variable Name: @EmailAddress   Index:
>   346   ListID: 0 Source:  OMMCommon

Comment: Is that the full code sample? If possible could you post the full sample to help us figure out the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the VAR keyword:

```
VAR @ActionDate, @ActionDateTime
```

Comment: In addition to the SET statement?

Comment: You can either put in the VAR line (like above) or drop it altogether, beginning your code with the SET.  SET will automatically declare your variables for you with no VAR statement.  You can decide to do it manually (like in my example) but you'll need to follow the VAR syntax then.

Comment: The landing page is now returning an error below: 
The SET value expression is invalid. See inner exception for detail.
Script: set @EmailAddress = EmailAdress

Comment: Where are you getting EmailAdress?  In the query string?  This a landing page right?

Comment: Correct in that we are getting the email address from a query string and that this is a landing page.

Comment: Please post as much code as you can and we'll take a look.

Comment: I think I have figured the issue out. Looks like we are trying to convert a string to an integer. I'll research some more and see if I can drum up the exact data point that is causing this.

Comment: Here is the error we are receiving: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that we were not passing all the necessary variables to the landing page which was stopping the page from successfully executing the content.